# Chartist.js confused about how to create

Tags: chartist.js

I just want to use a simple chart on my website. I've found chartist.js. I've read
http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html

I've looked at the example on:
http://jsbin.com/qalewi/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm just unsure how to link the HTML and JS files. I initially created the HTML file and linked a chart.js file which had the code from the example. But when I run it nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is the complete html file you need

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chartist.js - Simple line chart</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="ct-chart"></div>
    <script>
  new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
    [0, 2.5, 3, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4]
  ]
}, {
  width: 500,
  height: 300
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that, nothing happened. I was running it on Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is right.If its not working on your system.Please cut the js file and add this file after div.
Kiran

Comment: Hello doohsam,

The above code is right.If its not working on your system. Please cut the line 
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
and paste after this <div class="ct-chart"></div> line.Like
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
Thanks
Kiran